# Will using Template Typdefs force us to duplicate iterator objects in C++23 even though "Deducing this" eliminates this problem?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++23, const-iterator, explicit-object-parameter

One of the problems **Deducing this** solves is duplication by making member functions cvref aware of the cvref-ness of the object the function is being called on. By declaring Alias templates (Template Typdefs) and returning them in the member functions rather than just returning **auto** are we not forced to have two iterator objects?

```
template <typename T>
struct const_list_iterator{

    typedef const T& reference;    
    typedef const T* pointer;

    reference operator*() const{/***/}

    pointer operator ->() const{/***/}
 };
```

and

```
 template <typename T >
 struct list_iterator{

    typedef T& reference;    
    typedef T* pointer;

    reference operator*(){/***/}

    pointer operator ->(){/***/}
 };
```

However, with Deducing this if the return type is **auto** can we simply have a single iterator object?

```
template <typename T>
struct list_iterator 
    
    template <typename itself>
    auto operator*(this itself&& self){/***/}

    template <typename itself>
    auto operator->(this itself&& self){/***/}
 };
```

Which we can use as below:

```
 template <typename T>
 struct list{
     using iterator = list_iterator<T>;

      auto begin() -> iterator {
          iterator(node -> next); 
      }

      auto begin() const -> iterator{
          iterator(node -> next)
      }

 };
```

So, will using typedefs force us to duplicate iterator objects?

Comment: Are you asking about the iterator types themselves or the `begin`/`end` overloads?

Comment: "*When we write iterators for collections we make two, one non-const iterator and the const*" Strictly-speaking, you never *needed* that to begin with. If your iterator is a template of the `value_type` of the collection, you could have made your "const iterator" type use a `const value_type`.

Comment: Your proposal allows me to mutate a `const list<T> list`: `list.begin()` returns a `list_iterator<T>`, which I then dereference with `*` to access the first list element and modify it. The const version of `begin()` needs to return a `list_iterator<const T>`.

Answer (score 3):

Your example code does not propagate `const` correctly from the container to the iterator. `begin() const` will return the same type as `begin()`. So any deduction on the `operator*` of the iterator is irrelevant; the fact that `const` was involved has already been lost.

In order to propagate the `const` from the container's `begin` to the iterator, `begin` *must* return a different type when the container is called via `const`. It could be a different specialization of the *same* iterator template (`list_iterator<const T>`, for example), but it needs to be a different type.

You can give `begin` an explicit object parameter and deduce the `const`-ness from it. But it'd just be doing this:

```
template <typename Self>
auto begin(this Self&& self)
{
  if constexpr(std::is_const_v<Self>)
    return list_iterator<const T>(...);
  else
    return list_iterator<T>(...);
}
```

If the `if constexpr` condition bothers you, you can stick it in a helper type metafunction:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
  requires std::is_const_v<U>
struct propagate_const { using type = const T; };

template<typename T, typename U>
struct propagate_const { using type = T; };

template<typename T, typename U>
using propagate_const_t = propagate_const<T, U>::type;

template <typename Self>
auto begin(this Self&& self)
{
  return list_iterator<propagate_const_t<T, Self>>(...);
}
```

Comment: I read this as a very roundabout "yes, we have to duplicate but not the entire iterator" answer to the question. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ramon: Where's the duplication? You don't have to write two iterators like the OP said. You don't even have to write two functions. You can write one function which returns two different types based on the `const`-ness of `this`.

Comment: But these two functions or two branches do exactly the same thing apart from the const modifier which is exactly the kind of problem deducing this was supposed to solve. Deducing this exists to solve this type of const non-const duplication so it's very much considered duplication. So much so that it got its own language feature to fix it. But it seems this case is not really covered by the feature.

Comment: @Ramon: "*Deducing this exists to solve this type of const non-const duplication so it's very much considered duplication.*" Nonsense. No version of the paper *ever* claimed to solve `const` propagation. It only ever claimed to stop duplicating code. And it does. With iterators, the code is not the same because `T` and `const T` are *not the same type*. It's not duplicate code if one of them *must* look different.

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. The idea of generic programming to me at least is that it allows you to merge commonalities and extract differences into a template or a concept and I think the ability to factor out constness and deduce it from the context to reduce duplication is very much part of the use case of deducing this. (Besides the many cute things you can do with it, especially with lambdas. But that is a different story.) But the level of verbosity in code at the end of the day is very much just personal preference. Being more explicit about constness has its advantages.

Comment: @Ramon: The problem you're citing is a problem with how C++ propagates `const`. If a type T has a member `U*`, a `const T` has a member of type `U * const`, *not* `U const*`. So long as this is the case, what you want can't happen. However, you could easily make a template called `const_if_const_t<T, U>` which results in `T` if `U` is not `const`, and results in `const T` if `U` is `const`. Then just return `list_iterator<const_if_const_t<T, Self>>(...);`

Comment: @Ramon: I've added an example of the metafunction approach, if having an explicit condition bothers you so much.